# SMTP not working on Azure websites on 64 bit mode

Tags: azure, smtp, 64-bit

I deployed an application to Azure websites several months ago and it has worked as expected. Yesterday, after Microsoft released a set of new features, I noticed that there is an option to change from 32bit to 64bit. I changed the web site configuration from 32bit to 64bit. All the site works except when I try to send emails via SendGrid using standard SMTP .NET library.

This is the exception that I get:

Access is denied" source="System" detail="**System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException** (0x80004005): Access is denied at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.GetFixedInfo() at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.get_FixedInfo() at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.get_HostName() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Initialize() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient..ctor()

This is the code:

```
var toAddress = new MailAddress(to, username);
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
using (var message = new MailMessage() {Subject = subject, IsBodyHtml = true})
{
    message.To.Add(toAddress);
    message.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Web.config:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="xxx@xxx.com">
      <network host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="587" userName="xxx@azure.com" password="xxxxx" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

My development environment is configured as 64bit and the application is able to send emails.
Any idea why does it fail on Azure 64bit mode?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you deploying your Cloud Service in `Full Trust` or `Windows Azure Partial Trust`?

Comment: I am deploying using websites. It is full trust by default.

Comment: I had the same issue. Switching it back to 32 bit fixed it. Does anyone have an explanation for the discrepancy?

Comment: I had the same issue and changing it back to 32-bit fixed it. Strangest thing. Would love to know why.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue and discovered that I had conflicting values in the web.config file and the Azure app settings.  I'm not sure exactly how these work in Azure because they don't seem to map directly to web.config app settings.  After removing all Azure app settings (and leaving the web.config) ones, email sent via gmail without issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll check my settings to verify if there is something out of place.

Comment: I ended moving to a web role and it works fine on 64bit. I stopped researching a possible solution for the website.